# sas ods to put table and graph in one excel spreadsheet?

Tags: graph, sas, sas-ods

I can us ODS to output tables to excel (using proc print or proc tabulate)and I can output SAS graphs (using proc gchart) to excel.  But I want to be able to have the table and graph on the same sheet in a workbook.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using DDE, you can run virtually every Excel command from within SAS, including copying and pasting stuff. There are decent tutorials here http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/161-30.pdf and here http://www.phusewiki.org/docs/2006/SS03.pdf For example, you could paste your graph inside the tabular output; or the other way around, put the table data inside a sheet with the graph.

P.S. Look at page 29 here, too http://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2007/appdev/MWSUG-2007-A01.pdf
probably it is something that you want.